# What is the relation between threads and concurrency?

Tags: operating-system

Concurrency means the ability to allow more than one tasking process at a time
But where does threading fit in it?
What's the relation between threading and concurrency?
What is the important link between these two which will fully clear all the confusion?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What about your research? Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) vs [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))

Comment: Understood I'll make sure about that next time I post here

Comment: I have been reading my question over and over and still not able to figure out what i did wrong here

Comment: You did not make anything wrong. The issue is that you should show some effort when you make a question. A thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a thread scheduler.  Multiple threads can exist within one process, executing concurrently and sharing resources such as memory, while different processes do not share these resources. So concurrency is the way to allow that one or more threads can run and shared resources, meanwhile a process have multiple threads that will not share resources with another process.

Comment: Alright now I understand, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are one way to achieve concurrency. Concurrency can be achieved at many levels and in many ways. Here are some of them from low to high level to give you a rough idea:

- CPU pipelines: at a hardware level, multiple instructions are executed in parallel (each instruction is at a different stage in the pipeline)
- Duplication of ALU and FPU CPU units. There are more arithmetic-logic units and floating point units in a processor that can execute instructions in parallel.
- vectorized instructions. Instructions which execute for multiple data.
- hyperthreading/SMT. Duplication of the process context.
- threads. Streams of instructions which can be executed in parallel.
- processes. You run both a browser and a word processor on your system.
- tasks. Higher abstraction over threads and async work.
- multiple computers. Run your program on multiple computers

Comment: FPU = Floating Point units? is that what you meant to say here?

Answer (score -1):

I'm new here but I don't really understand the down votes? Could someone explain it to me? Is it just because this question has (likely) been answered or because it's considered obvious?

Now that that's out of the way...

Nothing being executed on the CPU is from a "process" or anything else. They're all threads, scheduled and entirely managed by the kernel using a variety of algorithms to reach expected performance for any given application. The CPU only allows n threads, where n equals (cores * hyperthreads). In most cases hyperthreads will be 2 so you have double the core count to get logical CPU count. What this really means is that instead of 4 (for example) threads being run at once, it can support up to 8. Now the OS may have hundreds of threads at any given time, how is that possible? Well the kernel uses a variety of checks such as how frequently and long the thread sleeps to assign it a priority. Whenever the CPU triggers a timer interrupt the OS will swap out threads appropriately if they've reached their alotted time slice based on the OS determination of its priority.

Comment: I should add this same system exists for a single core CPU as well. There are a lot of technical differences in assignment but for the most part it just comes down to the OS recognizing fewer resources and so alotting less time for any given thread.

Comment: the kernel absolutely does have the abstraction of threads and processes. The linux kernel goes even one step further and everything runnable is a "process" and a thread is just a  kind of process.

Comment: Sorry, were you correcting something I said or just adding to it?

Comment: both. "Nothing being executed on the CPU is from a "process" or anything else. They're all threads, scheduled and entirely managed by the kernel " That's misleading at best. For example, as I've said, in the linux kernel everything that can run is a process.

Comment: Ah, my expertise is definitely with Windows but maybe you can explain a bit further for me. Threads are, regardless of OS implementation, executed by the CPU. The advent of multi process systems was primarily for security, logically separating processes from accessing the memory of another process. What did I say that differs precisely in Linux? They may consider a process a "kind of thread" but that doesn't really effect what I said, does it? They still have a thread scheduler to manage execution time slices on the CPU.

Comment: I guess the primary difference could be OS specific terminology, but in hardware (CPU) terminology it's still only threads that have code executed, and every major OS has some semblance of a thread scheduler.

Comment: They don't have a thread scheduler, they have a process scheduler. Anyway, you can say it's just terminology. But since you specifically mention the kernel, that is the terminology used by the linux kernel.

Comment: Fair enough, I think we're arguing semantics but I'll make sure to clarify my wording in the future so as to not cause any confusion.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation of how an OS can support more thread structures than its CPU has cores is misleading.  The hardware timer is just one source of interrupts that can change the set of ready threads assigned to cores, and failing to mention the vital IO completion interrupts from disk, network, UK, memory management etc. hardware is grossly misleading:(

Comment: What exactly is misleading about it? Of course the timer interrupt is not the only thing used by the thread scheduler, not even close, you could write several chapters describing all of its intricacies. He wasn't asking about this though, it doesn't seem relevant. I also don't know why any of your other examples are relevant, he asked about concurrency not synchronization. He specifically asked how threads are involved in more than one tasking process at a time. I don't really know why going into so much depth would be necessary for a satisfactory answer.

Comment: This is confusing to look at and as pointed out by others slightly misleading too